# Clarification of the counterexample without homotopy extension property

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

At [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1919224/953269) link a counterexample has been provided. I would like to ask for a clarification of why the space $X/A$ is contractible. Is it related to the fact the topology on the quotient is too coarse? How do I see it is contractible? Thank for your explanations!

Comment: Do you believe in the description of the open subsets given in the link? If so, this space is homeomorphic to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space . It is not difficult to see that this is contractible, and indeed it comes from the fact that the topology is rather coarse (it is not the discrete space with two points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that it is contractible by finding a homotopy between the identity and a constant map. Abstractly, the space can be written as $\{a,b\}$ with $\{a\}$ open but $\{b\}$ not open, a.k.a. [the Sierpiński space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). In such situation consider

$$H:X\times [0,1]\to X$$
$$H(x,t)=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if } t=1\\
a&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

It is continuous because $H^{-1}(\{b\})=\{(b,1)\}$ is closed, and $\{b\}$ is the only interesting closed subset of $X$.